# Why is `backface-visibility:hidden` not working on iframe?

Tags: html, css, iframe

The backface-visibility doesnt hide the iframe backface

I created a flip box with iframe element on both side, when flip, the iframe on the front side will overlay the iframe on back side, apply `backface-visibility: hidden` does not hide it backface, although it [shoud be](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_backface-visibility):

[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/vietanhfs/pen/GXpGEX)

```
<div class="flip3D">
     <div class="front">
        <iframe id ="frame" width="auto" height="auto" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/wZZ7oFKsKzY?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0"> 
        </iframe>
     </div>
     <div class="end">
        <iframe width="80%" height="80%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY" frameborder="0"></iframe>    
     </div>
</div>
```

I can fix this by making the front side iframe visibility: hidden on hover. But

**Question** : Why `backface-visibility` is not working on `iframe` ?

Comment: You could add a CSS animation that switches the iframe visibility at “half time” …?

Comment: Yes i can, but i dont understand why the iframe backface is not working, and if i use diferent transition-timing-function it visibility will not appear exactly when the flip box flip halfway

Comment: `.front` and `.end` are different, so they have different backfaces. I believe your single Element must be `transform-style: preserve-3d;`.

Comment: @StackSlave yes, thank you, `transform-style: preserve-3d;` is what it is missing, you could post an answer and i will mark it as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were missing `transform-style:preserve-3d;`?